# I can't get RSA encryption to work with my database

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, rsa, phpseclib

I'm trying to use phpseclib to encrypt PII before inserting data into my mySQL database.
I can seem to encrypt something, and put it into a database, but when I recall it, I can't decrypt it.

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX");
include('phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php');
$secret= 'Hello World';
$pubkey = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCunhp5XEEptnE/+jhfdTF1ryjr 756tUJs26RTKgVa/6isdO+SzTdHRvsOqle8Ze58Y9Qj8goVGkcsxrSHr+nEWcN6O oQK+e1Inux5PDwVOE9kiWbjDN4hs41+d6ZgdN6l8h4bhPeAVgQoS2F4a2TKMyLY5 dyzwj7RK98mLwbfaNwIDAQAB";
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadkey($pubkey);
$name = "apersonalname";
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($secret);
$storeme = base64_encode($ciphertext);
echo $storeme;
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `enctest`(`Name`, `SecretMessage`) VALUES ('$name','$storeme')");
$findsecret = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `enctest` WHERE `Name`='$name'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($findsecret))
  {
      $sm = $row['SecretMessage'];
  };

$return = base64_decode($sm);
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey('MIICXQIBAAKBgQCunhp5XEEptnE/+jhfdTF1ryjr756tUJs26RTKgVa/6isdO+Sz TdHRvsOqle8Ze58Y9Qj8goVGkcsxrSHr+nEWcN6OoQK+e1Inux5PDwVOE9kiWbjD N4hs41+d6ZgdN6l8h4bhPeAVgQoS2F4a2TKMyLY5dyzwj7RK98mLwbfaNwIDAQAB AoGBAJBl1/ix7IUFBOPmFIYD0LHD9nAdCDfEZ4Zh+rp3eHhdueeD5tzLpo3vVbkU IdQN4YPu5c6CVJoF6GUdCecthCOvQtHtIZq3Gc3Bg6e7lnc3TXek1rBvIooexwj7 wqi+kHOxDZIo271CHccZCOmimBIPfA2x+LpdEa41ftJpxdM5AkEA4JbhbCaCGTQe ra9vGs/GIa61Rhemp8Ei/CrQwE8IgeMTFEnWj7qz23851uwPcdXUV4KvN/JtsFnr m2wyd501KwJBAMcKDO/XDgHuZc9X06lp0rkTqH6ToP7iZFhGvQV7TPt0AsJ2ew8z BKXAAwAE1aVWmt1V2OfX2JgXYUJGjX9eASUCQQDIMzc25QzL0r4WLXBpAhWoKMjG dobEu1GoX7I9+zWmMvjq+PceoFt7qmmwwDT0UJw8de4jfSNyNHXl0gkavzSJAkAO bQ4O/BlJzouWgZkXuFHLlD8sHWsXzjTTqRzeHtevifMBQTEeIuZ9VPNitvb9Ks/C pww3kY9jRp6H/TEYQCn5AkBp/tVM5fh7zp3D0K22oj/0N4aDMPMJ+PiaIMVz8ATj sqX4tZ0dDJ1tInz7uiDM1WH/8JV48kI6EQ8V2ekct51T'); 
echo $rsa->decrypt($return);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Could you take out the database part first and try with just storing the value in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating two Crypt_RSA objects but only on the first one are you doing `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);`. Do it on the second one, too, and you should be good to go!

Comment: Adding the setEncryptionMode line in fixed the problem, and I managed to encypt, store, recall and decrypt the secret! Thanks!